# Select the option whose text is contained with a string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` with several `option` elements. Each option has an `id` and a `value`. This select is loaded with an AJAX request via jQuery.

There is also a string variable that contains text with which you would have to compare all the option values. If any of them are within this text, set the option as selected.

In this example you would have to select the `<option id="27">Mini 4</option>` which is the one inside the string `var mytexto`.

How do I get these two values, the id and the value?

```js
var mytexto = 'Ipad Mini 4 16GB/1GB Azul';
```

```html
<select id="nombre_modelo" class="form-control">
 <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select one model name</option>
 <option id="25">Ipad 3</option>
 <option id="26">Ipad 4</option>
 <option id="27">Mini 4</option>
 <option id="28">Mini Wifi A1403</option>
 <option id="29">Mini Wifi A1432</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What you **tried** so far *!*

Comment: I have only tried to go with "each" the select but I have not managed to separate each of them and compare it with the string.

Comment: Please add it to your *question*

Comment: If you loop through each `option` you could do something like `mytexto.indexOf($(this).text()) >= 0`

Comment: @Sylar, Hope this helps https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/JjdKQKY

Comment: Thanks for all, I'm sorry by the title and question, I have tried explain the possible better.
Now this working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mytext = 'Ipad Mini 4 16GB/1GB Azul';

  var options = $("#nombre_modelo")[0].options
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

    if (mytext.includes(options[i].innerText)) {
      console.log(options[i].innerText)
      console.log(options[i].id)
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="nombre_modelo" class="form-control">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select one model name</option>
  <option id="25">Ipad 3</option>
  <option id="26">Ipad 4</option>
  <option id="27">Mini 4</option>
  <option id="28">Mini Wifi A1403</option>
  <option id="29">Mini Wifi A1432</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know this tag ".includes" and ".innerText".

Now working perfectly thank you.

Comment: ".included" is used to check substring inside a string. you can also use indexOf to do the same. ".innerText" is used tot fetch the text inside the option.